# Product quantity is not updating in my ecommerce cart

Tags: php, html, mysql, e-commerce, cart

I am creating an ecommerce website in php. I had struck now on cart. My quantity of books is not updating, always it is taking default "1" value. I want a drop down list in "quantity" field where user can only buy maximum of 3 books from my site.

Here is my cart.php

```
<?php include_once("header.php");?>
<div id="products_box">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <table align="center" width="700" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
 <br>
 <tr align="center">
  <td style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px" colspan="4"><h2> Your Book(s) Details </h2></td>
 </tr>

 <tr align="center" style="font-size:20px; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'">
 <th>Remove</th>
 <th>Book(s)</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 <th>Total Price</th>
 </tr>

 <?php
 $total=0;
 global $con;
 $ip = getIp();
 $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";
 $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price))
 {
  $b_id = $p_price['cb_id'];
  $b_price = "select * from books where b_id='$b_id'";
  $run_book_price = mysqli_query($con, $b_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_book_price))
  {
   $b_price = array($pp_price['b_price']);
   $b_title = $pp_price['b_title'];
   $b_image = $pp_price['b_image'];
   $single_price = $pp_price['b_price'];

   $values = array_sum($b_price);
   $total += $values;

   if(isset($_POST['update_qty']))
 { 
  if(isset($_POST['qty' . '$b_id']))
   {


    $quantity = (int)$_POST['qty' . '$b_id'];
    $run_update = "update cart set qty='$qty' where cb_id='$b_id'";
    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $run_update) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $total = $total*$qty;

  }
 }

 ?>

 <tr align="center"> 
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]"  value="<?php echo $b_id; ?>"/> </td>
 <td><h3><?php echo $b_title; ?></h3>
 <img src="admin_area/books_images/<?php echo $b_image; ?>" width="100" height="100"  style="border: ridge"/>
 </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="qty<?php echo($b_id); ?>"  size="8" value="
  <?php
  $default_qty=1;
  if(!isset($_POST['qty']))
  {
   echo $default_qty;
  }
  ?>"/></td>

 <td> <?php echo "Rs.\n". $single_price; ?></td>
 </tr>

 <?php  } }?>

 <tr align="right">
   <td colspan="4"><b> Sub Total: </b></td>
   <td colspan="4"><?php echo "Rs.\n". $total; ?></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:12px"><input type="submit" name="remove_pro" value="Remove" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF"/></td>


  <td align="center" style="padding-right:20px"><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF" /></td>


   <td align="center" style="padding-left:12px"><input type="submit" name="update_qty" value="Update Quantity" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF"/></td>


  <td align="right" colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF; margin-right:10px"/></td>
  </tr>

 </table>

 </form>


 <?php

  global $con;
  $ip = getIp();

  if(isset($_POST['remove_pro']))
 {
  foreach($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id)
 {
  $delete_pro = "delete from cart where cb_id='$remove_id' AND ip_add='$ip'";
  $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $delete_pro) or die(mysqli_error($con));
  if($run_query)
  {
   echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
  }
 }
}

 if(isset($_POST['continue']))
{
 echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}

 if(isset($_POST['checkout']))
{
 echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>";
}


 ?>

</div>


</div>



</div>
<!--Content Wrapper Ends--->


<?php include_once("footer.php");?>
<!--Main Wrapper Ends-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can anyone has solution to the above problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never define `$qty` which is used in your query:

```
$quantity = (int)$_POST['qty' . '$b_id'];
$run_update = "update cart set qty='$qty' where cb_id='$b_id'";
$run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $run_update) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$total = $total*$qty;
```

Change `$quantity` to

```
$qty = (int)$_POST['qty' . '$b_id'];
```

Comment: sir, my first product is working fine now in cart, but the quantity of 2nd products not changing now also the corresponding "total price" of both the products is not changing.

Comment: Change `$total = $total*$qty;` to `$total = $total + ($single_price * $qty);` to get the total price.

Comment: thank you sir for your reply, but the total price is not coming correct & also I am having the problem with the 2nd product in cart table.

Comment: Sorry - didn't mean to mess up the total price. And where does the 2nd product get updated?

Comment: 2nd product is in the same cart. When i am changing the quantity value of 1st product then subtotal value is coming correct, but when i am changing the quantity value of 2nd product in same cart then it is not changing & also subtotal is also not changing.